# PayPal Web Payments Pro Hosted - Credit Card payment confirmation page

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

I've implemented [Website Payments Pro Hosted](https://www.paypalobjects.com/webstatic/en_GB/developer/docs/pdf/hostedsolution_uk.pdf) on my website. I can pay using the PayPal log in and it gives me the link to return to my store which is fine as I then display my order confirmation page to the user.

When the user decides to pay via credit card:

[image]

They are then redirected to a confirmation page I don't seem to have any control over:

[image]

**What I've tried:**

1. Setting auto return on in my preferences and setting a return url (both via the Profile and in my initial API call when generating the button.
2. Changing the Web Payments Pro confirmation page setting to `On my sites confirmation page`.

When the payment is taken via credit card, I'd like to redirect the user to my actual payment confirmation page. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that `showHostedThankyouPage=true` was causing this issue.

I am using the .NET button API to generate the request for the iFrame like so:

```
var service = new PayPalAPIInterfaceServiceService(GetConfig(request));
        var createButtonResponse = service.BMCreateButton(new BMCreateButtonReq
        {
            BMCreateButtonRequest = new BMCreateButtonRequestType
            {
                ButtonType = ButtonTypeType.PAYMENT,
                ButtonCode = ButtonCodeType.TOKEN,
                ButtonCountry = countryCodeType,
                ButtonVar = new List<string>
                {
                    String.Format("subtotal={0}", _salesOrderPriceService.GetGrossTotal(request.Order)),
                    String.Format("notify_url={0}", request.NotifyUrl),
                    String.Format("return={0}", request.ReturnUrl),
                    String.Format("invoice={0}", request.Order.Id),
                    String.Format("currency_code={0}", request.Order.Currency.Code),
                    String.Format("cancel_return={0}", request.CancelReturnUrl),
                    "billing_first_name=test",
                    "billing_last_name=tset",
                    "billing_address1=test",
                    "billing_city=test",
                    "billing_state=tes",
                    "billing_zip=test",
                    "billing_country=GB",
                    "template=templateD",
                    "paymentaction=sale",
                    "business=tset"
                }
            }
        });
```

I had `showHostedThankyouPage=true` included in the name value pairs which was causing the issue. Removing it sorted it out.

Comment: I suggest elaborating or rephrasing this as an answer to better help others who have the same problem in the future.